# How to fit the Header correctly

Tags: html

I have an adminHeader.php as belows,

```
<div class="main_content">
        <div style="width: 100%">
        <div class="header" style="align-items: center;font-size: 17px;">
             <a  style=" text-decoration-line: none;">Dashboard</a>
             <div> 
             <a href="#"  name="age" id="age" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal"   > <img src="../assets/images/logo.png" width="35" height="35" style="vertical-align:middle"/> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?></a>
             <a href="logout.php" style="margin-left: 2em;"><i class="fa fa-toggle-left"></i> logout</a>
            </div>
    
</div>
```

I need to use this header on top of my page as follows,

[image]

So I implemented as follows,

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Anomaly Monitoring Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  


</head>


<div class="wrapper">
     
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h2> Dashboard</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        
    </ul> 
    
</div>
    <div class="main_content">
       <?php
            include "./adminHeader.php";
              
        ?>

      </div>
    </div>
 
</div>
```

But I can see the rendered HTMl as below,

[image]

And I need to scroll to see all the fields. Can someone help me to fit this to the screen? '

update:
Here is my css class.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}



.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}



.wrapper .main_content{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 220px;
  
}



.wrapper .main_content .header{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #717171;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
    
}

.wrapper .main_content .info{
  margin: 20px;
  color: #717171;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.wrapper .main_content .info div{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.error {
    color: red;
}
.vega-actions {display: none}

h3 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
font-weight: 50;
font-size: 10px;
margin-top:0px;
display: block;
color: #404040;
text-align: right;
border-top:3px solid #000;

}

.card {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
  }
```

Can someone show me what should I include in css file to show as I required?

Comment: Since this looks like tabular data, you should be using a `<table>` which would make this all easier.

Comment: where are css files? i recommend use css grid for page styling.

Answer (score 0):

try flexbox or grid layout
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

for flexbox layouts use the display: flex on the container and add flex-flow-column for a vertical flexible layout. Then set you width and heights to your needs, with flex-shrink: 0 for elements with fixed width or height.

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
}

.sidebar {
   width: <sidebar width>;
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}

.main-content {
   width: calc(100% - <sidebar width>);
   display: block | <or flex or grid, ...>;
}
```